# How to iterate over list of slices?

Tags: python, loops, numpy, slice

I couldn't find the solution to a performance enhancement problem.

I have a 1D array and I would like to compute sums over sliding windows of indices, here is an example code:

```
import numpy as np
input = np.linspace(1, 100, 100)
list_of_indices = [[0, 10], [5, 15], [45, 50]] #just an example
output = np.array([input[idx[0]: idx[1]].sum() for idx in list_of_indices])
```

The computation of the `output` array is extremely slow compared to numpy vectorised built-in functions.
In real life my `list_of_indices` contains tens of thousands `[lower bound, upper bound]` pairs, and this loop is definitely the bottle-neck of a high performance python script.

How to deal with this, using numpy internal functions: like masks, clever `np.einsum`, or other stuff like these ?
Since I work in HPC field, I am also concerned by memory consumption.

Does anyone have an answer for this problem while respecting the performance requirements?

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO! Please avoid adding information irrelevant to the problem in your questions. Also consider reading the [help] which explains how to ask good questions. In particular, this question seems more appropriate for CodeReview site, not SO.

Comment: It is very easy to mis-use numpy and bloat your script's memory footprint with huge arrays.  At least the way it's written now, I find the question relevant to SO.

Comment: Most numpy 'vectoriztion' questions are answered in SO even though they are technically about code speedup.

Comment: `np.r_` concatenates slices.  It's code might reveal some tricks that could speedup your solution.  Are the windows irregular in length and spacing and/or overlap?

Comment: Thanks for your tip, and yes the windows can overlap, are of various lengths (from 2 points to more or less 100 points), and can start at very different positions in the input array. I tested the same approach with a pur fortran code and the slow-down is also visible. I suspect it's cache problems, etc.. leading to the impossibility for the compiler to optimize cleanly. Actually I think frank128791 idea of using `cumsum` is the good trick.

Comment: In my crude time tests, the `cumsum` approach is substantially better then either of the other 2.

Answer (score 1):

If:

- `input` is about the same length as `output` or shorter
- The `output` values have similar magnitude

...you could create a `cumsum` of your input values.  Then the summations turn into subtractions.

```
cs = np.cumsum(input, dtype=float32)  # or float64 if you need it
loi = np.array(list_of_indices, dtype=np.uint16)
output = cs[loi[:,1]] - cs[loi[:,0]]
```

The numerical hazard here is loss of precision if `input` has runs of large and tiny values.  Then `cumsum` may not be accurate enough for you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple approach to try: Keep the same solution structure as you already have, which presumably works.  Just make the storage creation and indexing more efficient.  If you are summing many elements from `input` for most indexes, the summation ought to take more time than the `for` looping.  For example:

```
# Put all the indices in a nice efficient structure:
idxx = np.hstack((np.array(list_of_indices, dtype=np.uint16),
    np.arange(len(list_of_indices), dtype=np.uint16)[:,None]))
# Allocate appropriate data type to the precision and range you need,
# Do it in one go to be time-efficient
output = np.zeros(len(list_of_indices), dtype=np.float32) 
for idx0, idx1, idxo in idxx:
    output[idxo] = input[idx0:idx1].sum()
```

If `len(list_if_indices) > 2**16`, use `uint32` rather than `uint16`.